# convexityDefects in OpenCV-Python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am new to OpenCV-Python.
I am trying to get the convexityDefects, I have the following code as shown below.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('s4.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 127, 255,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)
cnt = contours[0]

hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints = False)
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)

# some codes here.....
```

---

But when I run the codes I got an error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jasonc/Desktop/Pyhton/convexityDefects", line 11, in <module>
    defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)
error: ..\..\..\OpenCV-2.4.4\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:1969: error: (-215) ptnum > 3
```

What's wrong?  I searched the internet and most of the example looks the same.

Comment: so, you need more than 3 points for convexityDefects. make sure, cnt contains more than 3 elements.

Comment: When i printed out cnt i got this result: [ [[394 638]] [[395 638]] ]. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1) is giving you a list of separate contours instead of a single contour. In the tutorial from which you got this code the star image is nice and smooth so the findContours command returns a single contour at contour[0]. What ever s4.jpg is must not be smooth and continuous and therefore findContours is returning a list of contours. One solution to this would be to meager all the contours.

```
numberofpoints = 0
for contour in contours:
  for point in contour:
    numberofpoints = numberofpoints +1

allcountours = np.zeros((numberofpoints,1,2), dtype=np.int32)
count = 0
for contour in contours:
    for point in contour:
      allcountours[count][0] = [point[0][0],point[0][1]]
      count = count + 1
cnt = allcountours
```

this should give you one big contour in allcontours. Therefore cnt = allcountours should give you the right solution.

I had the same problem when trying track create a convex hull and defects for a image of a hand.